# How to move image to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner, I want to ask how to move the user and stars to the bottom?

[image]

There is code:

```css
.box-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  gap: 9rem;
}

.box-container .box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(211, 173, 127, 0.2);
  background-color: var(--ljub);
}

.box-container .box p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: var(--bela);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.box-container .box .user {
  height: 7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.box h3 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--bela);
}

.box-container .box .stars i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--kafa);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="images/Utisci/quote.png" class="quote" loading="lazy">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <img src="images/Utisci/women.png" class="user" loading="lazy">
  <h3>NAME</h3>
  <div class="stars">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you see any other problem in the code or approach, it will help me a lot!

Comment: Your question was edited to have a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). If you can edit your question further so that the stack snippet demonstrates the problem (It is currently broken) that would be great

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do to solve this problem is use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

First, let's recognize what you want. You want the quote mark and the text at the top of the container boxes, and you want the avatar image and the name and the stars at the bottom. To do this, first you need to slightly modify your markup to add wrapping div elements.

What you want is for the quote mark and the text to be grouped together, and the avatar picture, the name, and the stars to be grouped together. To do that we wrap them in a div. Give these wrappers class names so that you can add styling to them as well (such as padding, margin, text-alignment, etc)

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="review-text-wrapper">
    <img src="images/Utisci/quote.png" class="quote" loading="lazy">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-stars-wrapper">
    <img src="images/Utisci/women.png" class="user" loading="lazy">
    <h3>NAME</h3>
    <div class="stars">
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now that these elements are grouped, what you want to do is apply flexbox properties to the box so that the first group sits at the top and the second group sits at the bottom.

```css
.box-container .box {
  /* .. Other box styles */

  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

First we turn on flexbox properties with `display: flex`. Then we set the direction that the elements will flow, the default is `row` but we want to set it to `column`. We don't need the elements to wrap so we turn `flex-wrap` to `nowrap`. Then we set how the elements will be defined along the cross-axis of their direction with `align-items`. Since we set the `flex-direction` to `column` this will set the items in the horizontal center of the box. Then we use `justify-content` to define how the flex child elements will be set along the axis of the direction. Since the direction is column, this is how the items will arrange themselves vertically. We use `space-between` to say that they will have no space on the top or bottom, on the outside of the child elements, and put all available space in between them.

If you do this, what you should see is that the quote mark and the review text sit at the top of the box and the name and avatar and the stars will sit at the bottom. The space between them will *flex* based on how much vertical space the review takes up.

For the wrapping classes, you may also need to add `text-align: center` to keep the text and images centered within the wrappers.

```css
.review-text-wrapper,
.user-stars-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

To learn more about flexbox, refer to the flexbox link at the top of this answer or to [this cheat sheet guide from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Here is a demo of this code sample working using placeholders and some dummy values. You can also see it working in [this codepen] (https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/BabxLJE) that has two boxes with different text sizes to better show it working. Here is the [codepen demo result](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/live/BabxLJE) without the code.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 420px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.review-text-wrapper,
.user-stars-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="review-text-wrapper">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/50" class="quote" loading="lazy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eum adipisci, sequi cum quae ipsam reprehenderi?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-stars-wrapper">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/100" class="user" loading="lazy">
    <h3>NAME</h3>
    <div class="stars">⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this according to given css. Add `display:flex`, and `flex-direction:column`. Also add `flex:1` to make it take the full space

```css
.box-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  gap: 9rem;
}

.box-container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(211, 173, 127, 0.2);
  background-color: var(--ljub);
}

.box-container .box p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: var(--bela);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.box-container .box .user {
  height: 7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.box h3 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--bela);
}

.box-container .box .stars i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--kafa);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/862687586/fr/vectoriel/ic%C3%B4ne-de-lapostrophe.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=rHd25EbVAxujlX_5ZSFBZjMTEPjKwW6rl58VqzShqIc=" width="30vw" class="quote" loading="lazy">
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="user" loading="lazy">
    <h3>NAME</h3>
    <div class="stars">
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
    </div>
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-basis: 0%` by setting the `flex` shorthand property is probably not what you want here.

Comment: You are correct Stephen, I might have been right if added a wrapping div  to image h3 and stars.div with flex:1 shorthand. Anyway your approach with justify-content:space-between is the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

I did some small edits to give you a container and wrapped the called out name and stars as an element I wrapped as a div with class footer, removed the grid gap then added this: `.footer { margin-top: auto; }`

Probably some other CSS that might be simplified but not part of this question.  PS: I guessed some random colors and assigned some to the names.

```css
body {
  --kafa: #7E3517;
  --bela: #ffffff;
  --ljub: #7F00FF33;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.box-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
}

.box-container .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(211, 173, 127, 0.2);
  background-color: var(--ljub);
  color: red;
}

.box-container .box p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: var(--bela);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.box-container .box .user {
  height: 7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.box h3 {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--bela);
}

.box-container .box .stars i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--kafa);
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/Utisci/quote.png" alt="Q" class="quote" loading="lazy">
    <p>TEXT longer wrapper some giraffes were found in the kitchen eating lolly pops and oak leaves.</p>
    <img src="images/Utisci/women.png" alt="W" class="user" loading="lazy">
    <div class="footer">
      <h3>NAME</h3>
      <div class="stars">
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt">^</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could modify the **.box-container** to be **relative** with **height: 100%;** and then place everything you need on the bottom on that container into a "bottom" class.

```css
    .box-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap: 9rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box-container .box {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3rem 5rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(211, 173, 127, 0.2);
    background-color: var(--ljub);
  }

  .box-container .box p {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: var(--bela);
    padding: 2rem 0;
  }

  .box-container .box .user {
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  .box h3 {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: var(--bela);
  }

  .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/Utisci/quote.png" class="quote" loading="lazy" />
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <div class="bottom">
      <img src="images/Utisci/women.png" class="user" loading="lazy" />
      <h3>NAME</h3>
      <div class="stars">
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star">*</i>
        <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt">*</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```